# Angular2 update value from http request

Tags: javascript, angular, httprequest

I have a simple service does a few get requests:

```
getDevices() {
  return this.http.get('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

getVariable(deviceId: string) {
  return this.http.get('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/' + deviceId + '/running')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

In my component I have the following function which fetches devices and adds the variable from getVariable to each device in this.devices.

```
  getDevicesAndRunning() {
    function callback(array, data, res) {
      array.push(Object.assign(data, {"running": res.result}))
    }
    this.photonService.getDevices()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          const myArray = [];
          for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

            if (data[i].connected) {
              console.log(data, i);
              this.photonService.getVariable(data[i].id)
                .subscribe(
                  callback.bind(this, myArray, data[i])
                );
            };
          }
          this.devices = myArray;
        }
      );
  }
```

I can then call `getDevicesAndRunning()` to update the list of devices and iterate over them in the view. Currently I'm doing this in `OnInit` and whenever the user clicks a button. However, since `this.devices` gets repopulated each time the function is called the user sees a blank list for however long the request takes to respond. All I want is for the `res.result` to be updated, not the entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this sort of thing by not using the originally returned list. I implemented something like this for an app that's in production now and it works great.

When you get the original list, stash it off to the side. Create a copy and use that for the display.

When you need to update it, get the new list, copy it, and now you have a lot of options; old vs. new, replace old, combine old and new, display delta, etc. There's some nice ES6 functions, not native but simple enough, out there to do things like unions, diffs, etc, and of course lodash will serve.

True, this involves a copy of the list, but in the app I built I dealt with thousands of objects and at least six lists simultaneously and never had any problems with memory etc. You just have to remember to clean it up if necessary.

Comment: This sounds like an acceptable solution, however I'm having some issues cloning the old array into a new one. This needs to happen inside the getDevices subscribe function, right? Otherwise the old array won't be populated before we try to splice it? For some reason this.devices = this.oldDevices.slice(); returns undefined, even it it happens after oldDevices is populated.

Comment: I wouldn't try splicing it, in fact I only use splice and slice (in-place edits) when I have to (some search/sort algs and whatnot). Again, leave the old one alone, and build the new one from it using map, filter, etc.

Comment: Also remember, angular.copy is your friend. EZ copies. If you need deep copies you can do it too, a little searching on the topic will show you the way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are bulk updating the list you are blanking it out while the refresh is happening.  You will need to preserve the array and alter it on the fly.  Splice out the removed items and push in the new ones.  Let the sort function angular provides do the rest of the work.